# Laravel Blade returns a "Undefined property" on an object that has a defined property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a model with several fields, including two text fields that store JSON lists of dictionaries. One of them, that stores image data, is working fine; however a second one that stores a list of dicts with links returns a `Undefined property: stdClass::$title` when I try to access the property from a blade template.

All of the other properties (including the images JSON converted to an array of objects) are rendering fine if I remove the call to my links property.

I've tried to `dd()` the links property and it both shows that it's set, it's an array, and it's full of objects with both the properties (title, url) that I'm trying to access when it fails.

Once I try to actually access them, however, I get that `Undefined property` for the exact properties I'm trying to access.

Wondering if anyone has encountered anything like this? The really odd thing is that the images JSON data is rendering without a single problem. It's all tied together with Route Model binding, which is verified to be working.

### Property getters in Eloquent Model

```
public function getLinksAttribute() {
    if (!empty($this->attributes['links'])) {
        return json_decode($this->attributes['links']);
    }
}

public function getImagesAttribute() {
    if (!empty($this->attributes['images'])) {
        return json_decode($this->attributes['images']);
    }
}
```

### Section of blade template calling the link property, that fails

```
@if (is_array($artist->links))
<div class="links">
    <h4>Links</h4>

        <ul>
            @foreach ($artist->links as $link)
                {{ $link->title }}, {{ $link->url }}
            @endforeach
        </ul>

</div>
    @endif
```

### Section of blade template calling the images property, that succeeds

```
@if (is_array($artist->images))
    <ul class="images">
        @foreach ($artist->images as $image)

            <li>{!! Html::image(Html::buildS3Url(array(
        "basedir" => "artists", "id" => $artist->id, "prefix" => $image->prefix,
        "extension" => $image->extension, "conversion" => "display")
    ), $artist->name) !!}</li>

        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

### Json encoded data in database via tinker, and subsequent `dd()`

```
### links (doesn't work)
#tinker output
links: "[{"'title'":"test","'url'":"http:\/\/test.com"}]",,

# dd()
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#308 ▼
    +"'title'": "test"
    +"'url'": "http://test.com"
  }
]
### images (works)
# tinker output
images: "[{"prefix":1440693993,"extension":"png"},{"prefix":1440697822,"extension":"png"}]"

# dd()    
array:2 [▼
      0 => {#308 ▼
        +"prefix": 1440693993
        +"extension": "png"
      }
      1 => {#307 ▼
        +"prefix": 1440697822
        +"extension": "png"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Undefined property: stdClass::$title"

seems like in one of Your links missing title property

You can check it by:

```
@foreach ($artist->links as $link)
  <?php if(property_exists($link, "title")) : ?>
    {{ $link->title }}
  <?php else : ?>
    NO TITLE [DEBUG: {{ dd($link) }}]
  <?php endif; ?>, {{ $link->url }}
@endforeach
```

also I've found one thing:

```
links: "[{"'title'":"test","'url'":"http:\/\/test.com"}]",,
```

Your element field is    **'** title **'**    (with '), but it must be **"title": "test"**

You can fix it by removing single quotes in paramater names.

Comment: That'd be strange, since that JSON I pasted is the only thing it's loading. According to a dd() on the $link object, it does in fact have a title, it's just when I try to directly reference as $link->title. And yes, that doulbe/single quote business is weird, isn't it? That's coming directly from a json_encode call on an array of arrays. It's probably the best lead, but seems potentially like an issue with PHP as opposed to Laravel.

Comment: After tinkering around in the php interactive shell, I think the Laravel $request object is somehow adding single quotes to the keys, before I JSON encode. I tried json_decoding that exact JSON string and accessing the properties, and I get the same Undefined error. I then made the array of arrays from scratch and json_encoded, no single quotes, and the decoding/property access was fine.

Comment: It's those extra single quotes. A blade Html::macro was literally taking an input name I was passing, `links[$key]['title']`, with the single quotes, and passing them as part of the key. Thanks for pointing that out, possibly time for me to get some new reading glasses.